# dataTransfer not working correctly in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have noticed is that my code gives different output between browser versions.
Oddly using this with IE11 returns the path to the image and with chrome it returens the element ID.
My question is, how do I need to alter my code for it to work?

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#test1, #test2, #test3").click(function testfunc(event) {
                var testvar = event.target.tagName;
                var testvarr = $(this).attr('id');
                var testvarrr = $(testvar + "#" + testvarr).attr("src");
                var target = $(event.target);
                alert(testvar);
                alert(testvarr);
                alert(testvarrr);// debug I will use this later for a overlay in the same window
            });
        })
        function allowDrop(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
        }
        function drag(ev) {
            ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id); // this is different between browsers 
        }

        function drop(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
            var array = ["#een", "#twee", "#drie"];

            for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                if($(array[i]).children().length < 1 && $(ev.target).attr('id') == array[i].replace("#", "")) {
                        if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') !== -1 || navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Trident/') > 0) {
                            alert("hi you use IE");
                            alert(data);// returns the location of the image
                            document.getElementById(array[i].replace("#", "")).appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
                        }else{ 
                            document.getElementById(array[i].replace("#", "")).appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
                            alert("hello");
                            alert(data); // returns the ID of the element
                        }
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
    <div class="midden">
        <div id="een" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
        <div id="twee" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
        <div id="drie" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    </div>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <img id="test1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" onclick="function testfunc(event)" src="ster.gif" width="118" height="69">
    <a href="ster.gif" target="_blank"><img id="test2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" onclick="function testfunc(event)" src="ster.gif" width="118" height="69"></a><br>
    <a href="ster.gif" target="_blank"><img id="test3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" onclick="function testfunc(event)" src="ster.gif" width="118" height="69"></a>
```

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test1, #test2, #test3").click(function testfunc(event) {
      var testvar = event.target.tagName;
      var testvarr = $(this).attr('id');
      var testvarrr = $(testvar + "#" + testvarr).attr("src");
      var target = $(event.target);
      alert(testvar);
      alert(testvarr);
      alert(testvarrr); // debug I will use this later for a overlay in the same window
    });
  })

  function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  }

  function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id); // this is different between browsers 
  }

  function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    var array = ["#een", "#twee", "#drie"];

    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if ($(array[i]).children().length < 1 && $(ev.target).attr('id') == array[i].replace("#", "")) {
        if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') !== -1 || navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Trident/') > 0) {
          alert("hi you use IE");
          alert(data); // returns the location of the image
          document.getElementById(array[i].replace("#", "")).appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        } else {
          document.getElementById(array[i].replace("#", "")).appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
          alert("hello");
          alert(data); // returns the ID of the element
        }
        return;
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="midden">
  <div id="een" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <div id="twee" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <div id="drie" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
</div>
<p id="demo"></p>
<img id="test1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" onclick="function testfunc(event)" src="ster.gif" width="118" height="69">
<a href="ster.gif" target="_blank">
  <img id="test2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" onclick="function testfunc(event)" src="ster.gif" width="118" height="69">
</a>
<br>
<a href="ster.gif" target="_blank">
  <img id="test3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" onclick="function testfunc(event)" src="ster.gif" width="118" height="69">
</a>
```

Update:

Okay I fixed the code there were two things that I changed:

-changed target to srcElement. 
-removed the a tags(parents of images)

The a tag was removed because it changed the outcome of the data variable.(this wasn't a problem with chrome)
So overall it seems that it might have been a problem with browser compatibility.

Code that I changed from:
`ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.srcElement.id);` to:
`ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);`

Comment: You might want to look at the drag event ... `srcElement` Gets the element that the event was originally dispatched to. `Target` Gets the element that is the target of the event.  You might be grabbing the incorrect piece of data ...

Comment: okay I changed the code and it now looks like this:http://pastebin.com/1hqq1rc4 
sorry if I sound lazy, I am still trying to get the hang of javascript.(and pasting code in the comments seems harder then I thought)

Comment: You can post updated into the question, if you like ... just mark then as UPDATES ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I fixed the code there were two things that I changed:

-changed target to srcElement.
-removed the a tags(parents of images)

The a tag was removed because it changed the outcome of the data variable.(this wasn't a problem with chrome)
So overall it seems that it might have been a problem with browser compatibility.

Code that I changed from:
`ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.srcElement.id);` to:
`ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);`

I want to thank rfornal for helping me with this question.